# How to export multiple ranges to PDF on one sheet only using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to export multiple ranges to PDF and fit on one single sheet only, what property am I missing to fix this issue? Right now it is split to two multiple sheets on one PDF.

```
Sub Printing()
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.Zoom = False
.Orientation = xlPortrait
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = False
.PrintArea = ActiveSheet.Range("A01:R6, A26:R50").Address
 End With
 Application.PrintCommunication = True

 fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.pdf"
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
 Type:=xlTypePDF, _
 Filename:=fname, _
 Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
 IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 OpenAfterPublish:=True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please post or provide a link to a screenshot as to what the problem is?

Comment: Hello, I managed to solve it by merging everything to one single range

Comment: Could you post the change you made, for others too?

Comment: .PrintArea = ActiveSheet.Range("A01:R50").Address Using only one continuous range, but will not work if you insist on multiple range

Comment: Yes, but this includes some cells you don't want. Put your logic/code for merging

Comment: That I do not know how to do.

Comment: You could create a new worksheet, link the cells in that worksheet to the cells that you want to export. Then you could just export from the new worksheet.